# Where do I find the links for duplicate questions?

Tags: support, duplicates

In general, where are links to duplicate questions located when a post is tagged as a duplicate?

This link is just an example of one of the many times I've been unable to find the duplicate:  Where is the link?

[how to restore data after running rm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604311/how-to-restore-data-after-running-rm)

Where is the link?

[image: example problem]

Answer (score 12):

Links to duplicate questions can be found **directly beneath the question title** at the beginning of the question body:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dessert (and others...) for moving my question to an appropriate forum, answering my question and proving me wrong on my original assumption that an obvious question would get a "snarky" response, which it didn't!  I honestly could not find the link for 'duplicates' for more than a year.

Comment: @NW_Photo_Laureate You’re very welcome!